# GIT. Ignore changes to be commited

Tags: git

I have a Drupal multisite and have cloned it to setup locally. I have changed some setting files for db access. When I do a GIT Status I get...

```
Changes to be committed:
   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   .gitignore
    modified:   sites/default/settings.php
    modified:   sites/mysite1/settings.php
    modified:   sites/mysite2/settings.php
```

I don't want to commit these files I want GIT to ignore them.

I have added them to .gitignore but they are still being tracked.

I have tried running the following...

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

But this does nothing.

How do I tell GIT to ignore these files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have added them to .gitignore but they are still being tracked.

You need to remove those file from the index first (`git rm --cached -- ...`), which isn't a good approach if you want to keep them versioned.
And you risk to commit those changes by mistake.
But if you don't mid that, then that will allow those files to be ignored.

To ignore them locally, you also can try:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree -- <file>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vonc I will add your solution to the brain bank.

Answer (score 0):

I had to perform a...

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

Then commit the Deleted files

Sorted

Comment: That is what I described first.